# How to print max and min value?

Tags: java, types, int

Is it possible to print the maximum and minimum value of integer data type? If yes then how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each of the wrapper types has a MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE, except Boolean, Void and the MIN_VALUE of float and double is the smallest positive value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. You will get the max and min value.

Answer (score 4):

Simply reference oracle docs to see more related variables and methods

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html
[image]